# Complexity of Polynomial Multiplication

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to multiply two polynomials A & B each of degree 'd', in this there are basically two operations i.e. Multiply & Addition. In order to get an output polynomial 'C', how many total number of operations required?
I have searched a lot and I make assumption that total multiplication operations will be 'd^2' & total additions will be '2d-1'. Therefore total operations will be (2d-1)*(d^2).
    is this true? or false? and how?
Please suggest....

Comment: Check your solution for d = 3.

Comment: I think your time would be better spent working through a few examples with pencil and paper than searching and making assumptions.  Try out a few cases for `d = 1, 2, 3, 4` and see if you can't figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for make it easy for me, now i have calculated that number of multiplications is (d+1)^2 and number of additions is [(d^2)-1]. Therefore total operations will be {(d+1)^2 + [(d^2)-1]}     am I on right way sir?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - Thanks for make it easy for me, now i have calculated that number of multiplications is (d+1)^2 and number of additions is [(d^2)-1]. Therefore total operations will be {(d+1)^2 + [(d^2)-1]} am I on right way sir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A polynomial of degree `d` has `d+1` coefficients. So a simple implementation would require `(d+1)^2` multiplications. For very large `d` the number of operations can be reduced to `O( d log(d))` using FFT.

Comment: Schönhage-Strassen is an algorithm for integer multiplication; there is, however, a way to multiply polynomials in `O(d log d)`, using FFT (the same thing that the Schönhage-Strassen algorithm uses).